# Swagger support for documenting workflow

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Can Swagger be used to document endpoints in a specific order different than the default, for example the steps in a workflow?

The use case is to provide runnable documentation that shows each step in the happy path of a workflow. Users could then take the response from step 1 and use it in a request for step 2, etc. or choose to run a specific step in the middle of the workflow. It would be nice if custom text could be shown with each step as well to document the workflow route.

This might be supported by adding an annotation to specify the order in which to document endpoints for example.

Ideally this would be a built in feature, though a 3rd party or open source approach may work as well. None of the commercial tools obviously fit this use case (https://swagger.io/commercial-tools/), though I don't know them all and it's possible some of the test support could be leveraged.

Comment: What I've found so far. Sounds like a pretty good solution can be set up using: 1) projects, which allow defining a subset of endpoints (so create one for each workflow) and 2) setting display order through the position attribute in @Api